# Performance in unity at runtime (mesh creation) vs (assets bundle loading)

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes, assets, assetbundle, streaming-assets

I'd like to load a 3d model that contains several objects in real-time. I believe I have to two methods to do this:

- create an assets bundle that contains my model (all object) and loaded at runtime.
- load mesh data (vertex, normals, vertex colors) to create a mesh (all object) at runtime.

Currently, my data is presented as mesh data (vertex, normals, vertex colors) and I would like to know if it is better to load them on at runtime and create the meshes from them. Or is it better to create an assets bundle from the mesh and put it in the server and then load the assets bundle?

To simplify my question is it more optimize to use:

- (triangles, vertex, normals, vertex colors)?
- or use unity assets?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks like a question you can answer for yourself by prepping your mesh both ways, and profiling how long it takes to load in each case. That will give you an empirically verified answer that you know applies accurately to your data, target hardware, and game load context, and doesn't rely on hearsay from Internet strangers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I wanted to know if there is some optimization that unity does when generating assets bundle that leads to more rendering performance or better physics... I am not only concerned by loading time but more about rending and fps when the model becomes big for example.
Thank you again.

Comment: That also sounds like something you can answer by profiling. It does not matter the tiniest amount if Unity has an optimization that doesn't apply for your specific case, or if your case is so cheap that even a lack of optimization is not noticeable, so you always need to test your actual case to know for sure how it will behave.